# Durandal breaking Bootstrap's responsive menu?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, single-page-application, durandal

I'm in the middle of moving my application over to Durandal and have to say - it's been an absolute pleasure.  I love how everything just works.

One thing I can't quite figure out is my navbar.  If you resize the browser down to <768px (I believe that's the trigger) in the Durandal SPA template in VS, the menu items don't get pushed behind a button - they just stack.

The behavior I expected was the behavior seen here:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html

Is there a setting I'm missing?  If not, does anyone have any idea how I can re-gain this functionality?  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the source code of the example page and you will see that the button is this piece of code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

And what makes the navbar to collapse is the class nav-collapse:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <p class="navbar-text pull-right">
        Logged in as <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Username</a>
    </p>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

With that in mind, you can make the durandal navbar to collapse.

You would need to include the js file from bootstrap ( bootstrap.js ) in your html page.

Comment: Dummy mistake.  Thanks Julian.